# spring-2.5.6 jar is compile with which version of JDK. any ideas.?

Tags: spring

spring-2.5.6 jar is compile with which version of JDK (major and minor). any ideas.?
I have got the source code of the spring2.5.6 but when i compile it. it shows some difference from the jar.
In manifest also jdk compile version is not mentioned. appreciate any help regarding this..

Answer (score 2):

Do the same as this for 2.5.6.

```
>javap -classpath spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar -verbose org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils | more
Compiled from "BeanUtils.java"
public abstract class org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils extends java.lang.Object
  SourceFile: "BeanUtils.java"
  minor version: 0
  major version: 49
```

- J2SE 7 = 51 (0x33 hex),
- J2SE 6.0 = 50 (0x32 hex),
- J2SE 5.0 = 49 (0x31 hex),
- JDK 1.4 = 48 (0x30 hex),
- JDK 1.3 = 47 (0x2F hex),
- JDK 1.2 = 46 (0x2E hex),
- JDK 1.1 = 45 (0x2D hex).

Manifest of `spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Created-By: 1.6.0_27-b07 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
```